# Jupyter Notebook opens a blank page for all environments except base(root)

Tags: python, jupyter

I am trying to follow the TensorFlow API documentation. I have done all the steps and activated my tensorflow_gpu environment. In the C:\TensorFlow\models\research\object_detection I typed "jupyter notebook" and it opens me a blank page http://localhost:8889/tree.

I tried to open the Jupyter Notebook in my base(root) and it opens the dashboard but for the other environments it only gives me a blank page.

How can I avoid that? Thank you.

I tried to delete and re-install jupyter notebook for that specific environments. I tried to upgrade and downgrade the version of it. Nothing worked yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can still run the Jupyter Notebook in your base environment and make the notebook run with a different kernel (like if you are running the notebook in a different environment). In order to do so you need to install these packages in all of your environment:

```
conda install nb_conda nb_conda_kernels ipykernel
```

By doing so you will be able to see the kernels of all of your environments directly in base.

You will be able to start jupyter notebook in base, and once the notebook is running in your browser you can decide which kernel to use.

[image]

In the above picture I started Jupyter Notebook in my base environment, and having installed those packages in all the environments let me run any notebook with any kernel.

NB: My other environments are tf_lite1.13, tf_lite2, tf_night. Root will run the base kernel.